# django model filter with validate_unique

Tags: python, django, validation

There is an error that says 'invalid syntax'
but i am a newbie to django and python...
What is the error in this code?
The first if-block works well
The second doesn't...

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    is_joined = models.BooleanField(default = False) #if True, joined, else wish_member
    is_master = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    def __str__(self):
        if(self.is_joined):
            return self.person.name + " is a member in Group " + self.group.name
        return self.person.name + " wishes to join in Group " + self.group.name
    def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #super(Person, self.person).validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)
        #tests if there is already the same person in the same group.
        if(self.__class__.objects.filter(person_id = self.person.id, group_id = self.group.id,).exists()):
        raise ValidationError(
            {
                NON_FIELD_ERRORS:
                ('The person already exists.',)
            }
        )
    elif(self.__class__objects.filter(is_master = True, group_id = self.group.id,).exists()):
        raise ValidationError(
            {
                NON_FIELD_ERRORS:
                ('The master already exists.')
            })
```

Edits: noticed the dot missing.leaving it there for the credit who found it. Error occurs in:

```
elif(self.__class__.objects.filter(is_master = True, group_id = self.group.id,).exists()):
```

Comment: Why don't you try `unique_together`?

Comment: Oops sorry i didn't finish my writing and I posted.

Comment: The error is in the second block of if condition
elif(self.__class__objects.filter(is_master = True, group_id = self.group.id,).exists()):

Comment: @arulmr could you demonstrate an example of unique_together as an answer?? then i'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unique_together` to make a set of fields, taken together, unique. In your case, you specify

```
class Membership(models.Model):
....

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
                               ("person", "group"),
                               ("is_master", "group"),
                          )
```

This will make sure that `person` and `group` and `is_master` and `group` will be unique together. [Read more information here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

Comment: Thanks a lot. THis solved it
Now i'm wondering whether if all of these validations should be in
models.py for localhost's admin.
Am i supposed to separate these between models.py and forms.py??
Anyways, accepted as an answer!

Comment: Having validations in `forms.py` separately is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot between `__class__` and `__objects__` in the elif statement. It should be:

```
elif(self.__class__.objects.filter(is_master = True, group_id = self.group.id,).exists()):
```

However, that would give you an attribute error, and you say you got a syntax error, so there may be another problem I haven't spotted.

Comment: hey nice one!! i'm realizing i shoulda put more details in my question. Is there a way to edit my quesetion?